# How to fetch rows by applying multiple filtres to a single column in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in my sql server 2008 database:

```
MsgID    TrackerId    MsgContent

  1        123           red    //MsgContent corresponding to colour
  2        123          E2120   //MsgContent corresponding to model
  5        123           sam    //MsgContent corresponding to password
  1        111          orange  //MsgContent corresponding to colour
  2        111          M3420   //MsgContent corresponding to model
  5        111           pam    //MsgContent corresponding to password
```

I want a single query whose result is as follows:

```
TrackerId     Colour    Model    Password   

  123          red      E2120       sam
  111          orange   M3420       pam
```

So, how should I go about solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for pivot / unpivot

Comment: You should have a look at **[Complex PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: Take a look at this web site. It lists five methods for converting rows into columns: [Five methods converting rows to columns](http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.com/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html) A `PIVOT` statement is usually the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version using `PIVOT`.  My only problem with this is the unnecessary aggregate function.  I don't know your table definition, but if you have only the columns MsgID, TrackerID, MsgContent, then the CTE that selects the grouping, spreading, and aggregation columns to pivot is superfluous.  If you do have more columns, then keep the CTE, otherwise you will get null values in your results.

```
SELECT TrackerID, [1] [Colour], [2] [Model], [5] [Password]
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    MsgID, -- spreading column
    TrackerID, -- grouping column
    MsgContent -- aggregation column
  FROM Trackers
) p
PIVOT
(
  MAX(MsgContent)
  FOR MsgID IN( [1], [2], [5] )
) AS pvt
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59b0a/5/0)

You can also use a select for each type of value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TrackerID,
  (SELECT MsgContent FROM trackers t2 
   WHERE t2.MsgID = 1 AND t2.TrackerID = t1.TrackerID) [Colour],
  (SELECT MsgContent FROM trackers t2 
   WHERE t2.MsgID = 2 AND t2.TrackerID = t1.TrackerID) [Model],
  (SELECT MsgContent FROM trackers t2 
   WHERE t2.MsgID = 5 AND t2.TrackerID = t1.TrackerID) [Password]
FROM Trackers t1
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59b0a/1/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I do have more columns and pivot works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by joining the table to itself based on `TrackerID` and filter by `MsgID`.

Example:

```
SELECT 
     Colour.TrackerId, 
     Colour.MsgContent AS Colour,
     Model.MsgContent AS Model,
     Password.MsgContent AS Password 
FROM MyTable Colour
JOIN MyTable Model ON Colour.TrackerId = Model.TrackerId AND Model.MsgID = 2
JOIN MyTable Password ON Colour.TrackerId = Password.TrackerId AND Password.MsgID = 5
WHERE Colour.MsgID = 1
```

Comment: If there was no colour value than this would not return a row even if there are models or passwords.

Comment: My assumption would be is that that would be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pivot approach:

```
select TrackerId, [1] as Colour, [2] as Model, [5] as Password
from Trackers
pivot (max(MsgContent) for MsgId in ([1], [2], [5])) pvt
```

The only trick is that you need to rename the columns.  Here this is done in the `select` clause.

EDIT:

Daniel's comment is correct.  The problem is routinely fixed using a subquery:

```
with trackers(MsgId, TrackerId, MsgContent, extra) as (
      select 1, 123, 'red', 0 union all
      select 2, 123, 'E2120', 2 union all
      select 5, 111, 'orange', 8 union all
      select 2, 111, 'M3420', 9 union all
      select 5, 111, 'pam', 10
     ) 
select TrackerId, [1] as Colour, [2] as Model, [5] as Password
from (select MsgId, TrackerId, MsgContent
      from Trackers t
     ) t
pivot (max(MsgContent) for MsgId in ([1], [2], [5])) pvt;
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it assumes that the table definition only has the three columns.  If it has more, then you need to specify using a CTE the grouping, spreading and aggregation column.

Comment: You know until today I didn't know you could do Pivots without the cte.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select [TrackerId],[1] AS Color,[2] as Model,[5] AS [Password]
FROM 
    (SELECT [TrackerId], [MsgID], MAX([MsgContent]) as [MsgContent]
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY [TrackerId], [MsgID]
    )x
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([MsgContent])
        FOR [MsgID] IN ([1],[2],[5])
    )p
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/686a2/1)**